# py3exiv2 install on CentOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, exiv2

Does anybody successfully install py3exiv2 on CentOS?

I found this instructions: https://dev.exiv2.org/projects/exiv2/wiki/BuildingPy3Exiv2onCentos and followed them, however it looks like it's old.

I tried different solutions from the internet but none of them worked.

As of now, when I execute command: `python3 -m pip install py3exiv2` I received below error message:

```
g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -g -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -g build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/exiv2wrapper.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/exiv2wrapper_python.o -L/usr/lib64 -lboost_python36 -lexiv2 -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/libexiv2python.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python36
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried to install boost_python with yum and manually, but it still not working.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, using python3.10.

I solved it by manually locating libboost and symlinking it. Looks like LD is looking at the wrong location, so better fix `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (as described in installation).

In the meanwhile I fixed it with:

```sh
locate boost | grep python3
```

Which gave me `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python39.so`, so I symlinked it to `/usr/local/lib` (it's defined in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`):

```sh
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python39.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_python310.so
```